# Problems with Adobe PDF reader on Android 2.2.1

Tags: 2.2-froyo, adobe-reader

I'm using a tablet computer (Archos 101 internet tablet) running Android 2.2.1.

On this tablet, Adobe Reader is installed. Unfortunately, I have problems while reading PDF files: the rendering process is very slow and sometimes the text is not rendered at all. Instead, it is showing a blank white page or rough pixels. I have to scroll and zoom around to force a new rendering and if I'm lucky, the PDF is rendered then. This happens with big (MB) and small (KB) PDFs.

Is this a problem because of :

1. slow tablet hardware
2. crappy Adobe Reader software
3. pdf files?

Does anyone else have those problems? Would be a change to a different reader, for instance ezPDF Reader, help?

Comment: Try it out and see what results you get :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice @t0mm13b :-) I thought some else has these problems and I do not have to try around by myself ^^

Comment: I have got the same problem with an Archos G9 101 tablet. The rendering of some PDF files is incorrect with the Android version of Adobe Reader and correct on other devices. So it is not pdf files otherwise they will not have a good rendering on other devices.